# Bash: delete first line of stdin

Tags: bash, account, creation

I've created a script for account creation that reads from a csv file, i do not need the first line in the csv as it has the titles for the colums, im trying to delete the first line using sed 1d $file, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="applicants.csv"

sed 1d $FILE |while IFS=: read USERNAME PASSWORD SCHOOL PROGRAM STATUS; do

#------------------------------------------
groupadd -f $SCHOOL
useradd $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD -g $SCHOOL
if [ $? == 0 ]; then 
echo
echo "Success! $USERNAME created"
grep $USERNAME /etc/passwd
echo
#------------------------------------------

else
echo "Failed to create account for $USERNAME"
fi

done < $FILE
```

here is the csv file

```
Full Name:DOB:School:Program:Status
JoseDavid:22-08-86:ACE:Bsc Computing:Unfinished
YasinAhmed:22-07-85:ACE:Bsc Networking:Complete
MohammedAli:21-04-84:ACE:Bsc Forensics:Complete
UtahKing:22-09-84:ACE:BSC IT:Unfinished
UsmanNaeem:21-09-75:ACE:BSC Computing:Complete
```

Here is a screenshot of the output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5zPN.jpg

is there anyway to skip the first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Try using `tail -n +2 $FILE` instead of sed.</strike>

You're reading from the unedited file with the redirect at the end: `done < $FILE`. Try changing that line to just `done`.

Comment: It's still reading the first line, ive tried with awk aswell and nothing happens

Comment: if i get rid of the < i get the following ./bulk: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `$FILE'
./bulk: line 21: `done $FILE'

Comment: You need to remove both the "<" and the "$FILE" parts of the line. It's not needed since you're piping the contents of the file in at the start.